# Compile in msys2 mingw64 with -m32 option

Tags: gcc, mingw, msys, msys2, mingw64

Inside a msys2 mingw64 shell, I would like to compile a software with the -m32 option in order to run in 32bit mode.

I have installed mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain

But when I compile with -m32, I have the following errors:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
```

I am thinking of a libraries installation issue, but I do not know how to find them.

Comment: Have you tried checking the folders manually for those libraries?

Comment: Yes searched through a few directories but couldn't find them

Answer (score 1):

I used the mingw32.exe shell also under c:\msys2
Under this I installed:
pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-toolchain

Using gcc -m32 from the mingw64 bash shell seems to build i386 objs, (checking with objdump) but does not link sucessfully as you saw.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-m32` option if you use the gcc present in `c:\mysys2\mingw32\bin`.

If the folder is empty currently, go in:

1. `msys` console.
2. `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-toolchain` and use this command.

Refer [Subsystem](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-introduction) section of this document for more information.

Comment: Could you link a reference please

Comment: Actually, you need a multilib toolchain in order to build a 32-bit application in a 64-bit environment... https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Multilib%20Toolchains%28Targetting%20Win32%20and%20Win64%29/ray_linn/